# Npgsql.PostgresException: '28P01: password authentication failed for use even with the right password

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql, database-connection

I have an issue with connecting to a remote database through my Asp.net app. The thing is, it works when I use the same credentials through pgAdmin. Everything seems to come down to this line in web.config:

```
<add name="name" providerName="Npgsql" connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=database;User Id=user;Password=password;Integrated Security=true;Pooling=true;" />
```

Of course, I changed the name, database, user ID and password here because it's confidential. I use putty to bypass the firewall, it works just fine for my colleagues. Here is the error I get:

[image: Connection issue due to invalid password]

I checked the password many times with my colleagues, and we have the same one. It's also the same one as the one I use with pgAdmin. Oh, and even if I don't run my pgAdmin in the background and run my asp.net app alone, I still get the error (just in case there might be port conflict with 2 same ports trying to connect at once). Putty seems to be useless in my case, even if it has the same configs as my colleagues (config which works for them).

**Edit (01/25/2023):**

Changing methods in my pg_hba.confg from scram-sha-256 to trust leads to another error stating that the role "daniela" does not exist. The password isn't due to me misplelling it, as it doesn't have any special character and is the same which works for pgAdmin and Datagrip. The port is also not at fault here. I truly suspect my connection failing due to the firewall on the remote server (that's also a reason as to why I try to use puTTY, it's to port forward my way through it). I am also not concurrently running a postgres server locally, so it cannot interfere with puTTY.

**Edit (01/27/2023): SOLUTION**

I solved the issue. It was due to my postgreSQL intercepting my postman's requests before having a port-forwarding with puTTY. To solve it, I had to delete my postgreSQL, and it works now.

**Edit (02/01/2023): **

I didn't have to uninstall my postgreSQL, I could have simply deactivated the service.

Comment: "Putty seems to be useless in my case"  It is hard to figure out what this means in this  context.  What makes you think this has anything to do with putty?  You don't show any error messages putty has generated.  Putty is not magic, either it is not working and that is the problem, or it is working and the problem is something else.  What use would you expect putty to be, other than doing its job?

Comment: What error message is in the database server's log file?

Comment: @jjanes I am not very familiar with puTTY. My colleague told me to set it up, then let it run in the background to bypass the firewall of our server. It's so weird, how can it do that? It just feels like it does nothing, but it seems to work just fine for him. 

As for the error message in the server's log file, there doesn't seem to be anything new after doing "journalctl -n 50". On the other hand, when I make a successful connection with pgAdmin or Datagrip, there are stuffs.

Comment: If there is no error message in your PostgreSQL log file, that suggests that your code is not connecting to the right PostgreSQL server (so the error message are showing up in some other server's log file where you are not looking).  If you are running another PostgreSQL server locally, that would probably interfere with PUTTY's ability to bind that port and redirect it, so you would be connecting to the locally run server instead of the intended one.

Answer (score 0):

If you are specifying the user-name and password...you should remove:

Integrated Security=true;

the "identity" can be different .... and is probably changing the user you are specifying.

Integrated Security (under windows) means "use the identity that is connected to the PROCESS that is running the code".

Most times, when you are logged into your windows machine, the identity is "you".  If you pull up "Windows Services", you can see some deviations from this in-general rule.

See

https://www.connectionstrings.com/postgresql/

it goes through some of the concepts.

You'll note (at the URL I just mentioned), the "Integrated Security example (seen below) contains no user-name or password.

```
Using windows security
Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=myDataBase;Integrated Security=true;
```

Comment: I tried removing it, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Please post (in your original question) your latest complete connection string.